# Object shaking while applying horizontal movement by Accelerometer in libgdx Game(Android)

Tags: android, libgdx, accelerometer

I am implementing a game where I'm moving the bucket using accelerometer to collect the eggs falling randomly.I have implemented the code which works fine but the problem is Bucket at the bottom side shakes a lot while moving.I am new to libgdx game development so I am not able to trace the problem.Kindly help me to fix this problem.Thanks

Here's my render method:

```
public void render(float delta) {


        switch(state)
        {
        case Running:
        {
        camera.update();
        game.batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);



        game.batch.begin();
        game.batch.draw(splsh, 0,0,800,500);
        game.batch.draw(bucketImage, bucket.x, bucket.y);
        lastpos=bucket.x;


        for (Rectangle raindrop : raindrops) {
            game.batch.draw(dropImage, raindrop.x, raindrop.y);
        }
        game.batch.end();


        stage.act(Math.min(Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime(), 1 / 30f));
        stage.draw();
        Table.drawDebug(stage);


        float accelX = Gdx.input.getAccelerometerX();

           bucket.x=accelX*(-200);  // reading the accelerometer values

        if (Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.LEFT))
            bucket.x -= 200 * Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
        if (Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.RIGHT))
            bucket.x += 200 * Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();


        if (bucket.x < 0)
        {
            bucket.x = 0;
        }
        if (bucket.x >Gdx.graphics.getWidth())
        {
            bucket.x = 800 - 64;
        }

        if (TimeUtils.nanoTime() - lastDropTime > 1000000000)
        {   total++;
            spawnRaindrop();
        }


        Iterator<Rectangle> iter = raindrops.iterator();
        while (iter.hasNext()) {
            Rectangle raindrop = iter.next();

            raindrop.y -=100 * Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
            if (raindrop.y + 64 < 0)
            {
                iter.remove();
                dispose();
                game.setScreen(new EndScreen(game));
            }
            if (raindrop.overlaps(bucket)) {
                dropsGathered++;
            //  dropSound.play();
                iter.remove();
            }
        }
        break;
    }
      }
     }
```

Comment: Is this problem only when using the accelerometer? Or also with the keyboard control? And what does the stage do? Are there any actors added to it?

Comment: @Springrbua : only with accelerometer.thanx

Comment: You should dampen the accelerator values. Only move the bucket if `accelX` is greater than some value. You should tweak that value to something that suits your needs.

Comment: I have already done that..I'm checking wether it is <0 or >size of screen

Comment: @JigarPandya is this stil a problem or did you solve it?

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure if this is your problem, but i think so. You are seting the **POSITION** of your bucket depending on your phone tilt / accelerometer value, instead of the **SPEED**. A human cannot hold a phone without moving it, his hands always shake a bit. This could be the reason why your bucket shakes. Try doing the same as with the keyboard controll:

```
bucket.x+=accelX*20*delta;
```

Why *20 instead of *200? This is because accelX has a max value of 10. So if you tilt your phone to max accelX it is 10*20*delta and it is the same as if you are pressing the key on keyboard.

Just a little note: You are calling `Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();`, but you are in the render method and the render method has a paramteter `float delta`, which is exactly this `Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();`.

Comment: bucket.x+=accelX*20*delta; instead of bucket.x=accelX*200.
Note the += instead of =

Comment: Thanks it certainly helped to some extent

Comment: So does this stop the shaking?